# Анимация заднего фона js

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать движение заднего фона при нажатии на определенные клавиши?

Answer (score 0):

1. нужно добавить обработчики нажатия клавиш, например обработчик события [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/keypress)
2. внутри обработчика нужно менять стиль [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) на нужную величину по оси x или y